# d3.js Adjacency chart pan

Tags: javascript, d3.js, adjacency-matrix

I have an adjacency chart which has about 1000 nodes and to make it readable I need the chart to be scrollable on the x-axis. I have the below which outputs the chart by using the div's scroll bars though this is cumbersome.

How do I change the below to allow the chart to pan left and right on mouse click / zoom?

Cheers

```
var x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeBands([0, width]),
        z = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 4]).clamp(true),
        c = d3.scale.category10().domain(d3.range(10));

var svg = d3.select("#graph-item").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
```

Comment: To accomplish this you will want to add [zoom and drag](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6123708) to your svg, or just simply zoom if you do not need dragging.

Comment: Cheers JSBob, have applied both of those to relativly good effect in Firefox / Chrome (experiencing  chart flickering when dragging). Just need to work out a reset chart back to original view and replace my 'css overflow: scroll' with the correct zoom level and width for the window to be readable and then job done :)